# Hibernate-Envers Audit Query: Select latest entity revision where field was equal to value across all entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am trying to select the most recent revision of each of my trackedResource entities where a position_source_feed_id has particular value.

I have a functional PostgreSQL query:

```
select tr0.*
from
    trackedresource_aud tr0
where
    tr0.position_source_feed_id='7870b8b9-4b98-4ea7-8fb8-99746d7f0e85'
and
    tr0.rev=(
        select
            max(tr1.rev)
        from
            trackedresource_aud tr1
        where
            tr1.id=tr0.id
        and
            tr1.position_source_feed_id=tr0.position_source_feed_id
    )
order by
    tr0.rev desc
;
```

but I cannot seem to get an AuditQuery to match.

---

When I tried the above createNativeQuery, I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

maybe because of several UUID fields on the entity including position_source_feed_id

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the following query to work:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
YourEntity lastRevision = reader.createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( YourEntity.class, true, false )
  .add( AuditEntity.property( "position_source_feed_id" ).eq( feedId ) )
  .addOrder( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc() )
  .setMaxResults( 1 )
  .getSingleResult();
```

The way the query works you are asking Envers for all revisions of `YourEntity`, you're only interested in the query returning the actual entities themselves (excluding deletions) where the `position_source_feed_id` is equal to the provided value.  The result-set is is then limited to the highest revision number and it gets returned.

Comment: That is not quite what I am chasing... I am looking for the latest version of the every entity when it had that feedId